# How to convert the header as a new column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm working with pandas, and I'm trying to convert the header row of the dataframe to a column, i have tried the stack() function, but it looks not working for me.

I have a file which contains data as the follow, it has double header - date and temperature (min & Max)

```
      2/16/2020  2/16/2020   2/17/2020   2/17/2020   2/18/2020  2/18/2020   ......
         Min        Max         Min         Max         Min        Max
Paris    44         61          41          52          39         47
Berlin   47         59          42          52          41         45
Milan    46         64          40          46          37         44
.
.
.
```

Expected output:

```
City    MIN MAX Date
Paris   44  61  2/16/2020
Paris   41  52  2/17/2020
Paris   39  47  2/18/2020
Berlin  47  59  2/16/2020
Berlin  42  52  2/17/2020
Berlin  41  45  2/18/2020
Milan   46  64  2/16/2020
Milan   40  46  2/17/2020
Milan   37  44  2/18/2020
```

I tried to use `df= pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv.text), header=[1])` to select the second row as the header but how to set only City, Min, Max, and create 'Date' which the new column?

I'm grateful if you can help me.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

Read in your data as shown and transform. suppose your data is named as `my_data.csv`

```
df = pd.read_csv('my_data.csv',sep = '\\s+',header = [0,1])
df.stack(0).rename_axis(['City','Date']).reset_index()
Out: 
     City       Date  Max  Min
0   Paris  2/16/2020   61   44
1   Paris  2/17/2020   52   41
2   Paris  2/18/2020   47   39
3  Berlin  2/16/2020   59   47
4  Berlin  2/17/2020   52   42
5  Berlin  2/18/2020   45   41
6   Milan  2/16/2020   64   46
7   Milan  2/17/2020   46   40
8   Milan  2/18/2020   44   37
```

Answer (score 0):

I read your question as a struggle to read the dataframe, then stacking the columns to achieve the output you want. Assuming you have a `data.csv` file that looks like this:

```
        2/16/2020  2/16/2020   2/17/2020   2/17/2020   2/18/2020  2/18/2020
        Min        Max         Min         Max         Min        Max
Paris    44         61          41          52          39         47
Berlin   47         59          42          52          41         45
Milan    46         64          40          46          37         44
```

Your need to read it twice, once for the headers and once for the data:

```
# Read the headers on the first 2 lines
header = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep='\\s+', nrows=2, header=None)

# There are 7 columns but only 6 headers
# We have to manually create the missing one
header.insert(0, 'City', 'City')

# Make a MultiIndex containing the names of the 7 columns
names = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(header.T)

# Now read the data
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep='\\s+', names=names, skiprows=2)

# Then the transformation
final = df.set_index(('City', 'City')) \
    .stack(0) \
    .rename_axis(['City', 'Date']) \
    .reset_index()
```